# How this simple javascript script actually works (might be scoping)?

Tags: javascript

Can anybody break down for me into steps how this (it looks simple in the first place) is interpreted by the browser:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a);
```

it will bring `1`. If I would change a function name to anything else, etc:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    function m() {}
}
b();
alert(a);
```

it will alert `10`.

Comment: Arrgh, that example is so common that you even can put the full code in your favourite search engine and get helpful results…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The scope of a variable declared with `var` is the entire function in which it is declared, it doesn't start at the point of declaration. It's often described as [variable declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) and can be seen as a move of all variable declarations to the start of the function. For function definitions, both the declaration and the "assignement" are moved together.

```
function b() {
    a = 10;
    function a() {}
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function b() {
    var a  = function() {};
    a = 10;
}
```

which means you declare a new variable `a`, and the `a = 10` statement only changes the internal variable `a`, not the external one. We say the internal variable `a` shadows the external one.

In the second case, there's no variable `a` in the internal scope, which means the external one is used and changed (when looking for a variable, you go from the internal scope to the most external one following the closure chain).